# how to get text of the textview in the dynamically generated table?

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

i have written something like this....

```
TableRow  tr1;  
    TableRow  tr2;  
    TextView txt9;
    ...
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < strarr.length-1; i++)
    {
    strinarr = fun1.split(strarr[i].trim(),"^");
    tr1 = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
    txt1=new TextView(this);
    txt9.setText(strinarr[0]);
    txt9.setBackgroundColor(intblue);
    txt9.setTextColor(intwhite);
    txt9.setClickable(true);
    txt9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.i("pagename",strpagename);
        String currenttext = txt9.getText().toString());
    }
    }
    });
    tr1.addView(txt9);
    tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams));
    }
```

i am able to get text on click but the stupid thing is that i am getting text of last textview in the table on all the textview click event... if somebody could tell me how to catch textview's text on focus or touch it would be really help full...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change `String currenttext = txt9.getText().toString());` to `String currenttext = ((TextView)v).getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably maintain a list of ID's in the table and a list of corresponding texts. When the user clicks on the widget with the given ID, simply look up the text in the textlist and set it.

Comment: i can store all the information in the vector also... for that i need some text which user selects... if you could suggest something getting text on touch or something else.. it will be really helpful...

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList qty = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  qty.add(i);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
  Spinner tvQtySpinner = new Spinner(this);
  tvQtySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> aa =
    new ArrayAdapter<String> this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, qty);
  aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  tvQtySpinner.setAdapter(aa);
  tr.addView(tvQtySpinner);

  TextView tvRate = new TextView(this);
  tvRate.setText(value.getPrice().toString());
  tvRate.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
  tr.addView(tvRate);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id)
{       
  Integer value = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
  Float result = value*50;
  tvRate.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Here I am having 5 rows, each row having 5 dynamic spinners and text views. I am getting the selected value from spinner and doing calculation and am trying to set that calculated result in particular rows TextView. But when I set the calculated value in TextView it will set on last rows TextView.